# SQL CLR Function get data from another DB Server but hit error "Login failed for user 'Domain\ServerName'"

Tags: sql-server

I created a CLR table-valued function which is getting the data from another database server by using SQL login in connection string.

CLR function is installed in database A at server ABC.
The data that retrieved by CLR function is in database X at server XYZ.

With the SQL login in connection string, this is working fine.
With the AD login (SSPI) by adding impersonate process, this is also working fine.
However, with the AD login without impersonating then it is hitting error "Login failed for user 'Domain\ServerName'".

I'd done the below actions but still hitting the same error.

- granted SELECT permission for the AD account to call the function in database A at server ABC.
- added the AD account into the "log on as a service" and "log on as a batch job" in local security policy at Server XYZ.
- added the AD account in the Log On of "SQL Server" and "SQL Server Agent" services and restarted the services at Server XYZ.

Could someone please help me on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "a CLR table-valued function which is getting the data from another database server by using SQL login in connection string" sounds like a daft idea, why not just use a linked server?

Comment: By the looks of it, the CLR function is authenticating as `Domain\ServerName`. Can you show your full connection string, are you using `Integrated Security=true`? What does the SQL Server error log say on the remote server, full log detail please.

Comment: @Charlieface connection string is "server=XYZ; database=X; Integrated Security=SSPI". We are restricted to use linked server and therefore i go for CLR function.  The error showed "Login failed for user 'domain\servername$'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: xxxxxx]"

Comment: @AngieChuah When not using impersonation for regular connections, the security context will be the "Log On As" account of the SQL Server service. If SQL Server was configured to use a service account (or LOCAL SYSTEM, etc), then that account might not work across servers. What type of account is SQL Server service account? Can you create a real AD account that exists on both servers, and set SQL Server on ABC to use the real AD account as the "Log On As" account?

Comment: Looks like SQL Server is configured to run under either SYSTEM or NETWORK SERVICE. The machine account that it runs on is what is used over the network, and that account does not have CONNECT rights on the remote SQL Server. Side note: you can tell whoever made that restriction that it makes absolutely no sense: linked servers are not much of a security risk, CLR functions are.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky i'd created a real AD account on both servers and granted sysadmin. Somehow still not working, same error. sigh....

Comment: @Charlieface unfortunately we have no choice and got to follow the rule.  :(

Comment: @AngieChuah When you say you added the AD account to both servers, do you mean creating a local Windows account, or is this a real AD account via a domain controller? Did you update the SQL Server service on the ABC server to use the new AD account as the service account and then restart the service? If you did, then a logon error should show 'domain\new_account_name' instead of 'domain\servername$'.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky yes, it is a real AD account and have done as what you mentioned. Still not working after few trials. 
Anyway, I changed to other servers and use another AD account, and it is now working! Not sure what is going wrong in the previous testing. 
In this method, I need to set the AD account in SQL server service in each of the servers which installed the CLR function and i have more than 100 servers. hmmmm.... unless i go for impersonate...

Comment: Angie, what do you mean by "other servers"? Have you tried the first AD account on the "other" servers? What do you mean by "_In this method_"? Which method? Regarding "_need to set the AD account in SQL server service in each of the servers which installed the CLR function_", I believe that is what I was suggesting. (CC @Charlieface )

Comment: yes, i tried it after that, the first AD is working on the "other" server too. so it is not due to AD account issue. "This method" is the method that i am trying (set the AD account in SQL service, etc).